# What was the selection criteria for people Russia judges in the "Azov trial"?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, crime

[Based](https://www.justiceinfo.net/en/122197-day-defence-azov-rostov-on-don-military-court.html) on Western media, it seems to me they are judging pretty insignificant cases like cooks (of the battalion) and what not.  I do recall that Russia even [exchanged](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/ukraine-hails-return-45-azov-fighters-russia-says-3-pilots-released-2023-05-06/) some Azov combat personnel earlier in the war. And a bit of more search surprisingly finds that Russia apparently even exchanged some Azov [commanders](https://www.france24.com/en/europe/20230712-azov-commanders-return-home-a-diplomatic-win-for-ukraine-a-slap-in-the-face-for-russia).

So what exactly is the criteria for judging those they didn't exchange? Or did they like put every Azov member on trial, but only exchanged some?

Comment: Russia exchanged the valuable prisoners for whom it could get something in return. They seem to be trying everyone they have left who they can't get a decent ransom/reward for, but I haven't looked into the full list of who is being put on trial (if that's what you mean by "judging").