# Why doesn't Ukraine run more guerrilla attacks in Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

Ukraine does not appear to be doing much guerrilla warfare in Russia. Although such attacks are likely to darken the image of Ukraine in Russia, it is not particularly good anyway. Additionally, civilian casualties could be avoided or heavily limited by sticking to typical sabotage actions, so such attacks would likely not negatively affect Ukraine's international image.

Why are such attacks not more commonplace?

Note: the weapons provided to Ukraine by the West were given with the condition that they won’t be used in an offensive war, but it is likely possible for Ukrainian and pro-Ukrainian forces to do guerrilla warfare on Russian territory without the official involvement of the Ukrainian government.

Comment: There have been a number of arson attacks on recruiting stations as well as interference with trains, so sabotage has taken place, unlike this Q's premise.  And, predictably, have been labelled "terroristic" by Russian authorities too.  Then drones got flown at the Kremlin as well.  This question starts out flawed and faces the additional issues that the motivations for the supposed restraint are not going to be part of the public record, making this opinion-only.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, my gut feeling (see: opinion-based) is that those recruiting station attacks are local Russians. There are other attacks which were more effective, like those on military aircraft, which might have had sponsorship.

Comment: **Voting to keep open.** The stated close reason does not apply: *"Opinion-based: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers."* On the contrary, this question can and, in fact, has been answered with facts and citations. The answer by *Machavity* is an example. And the answer by *Ted Wrigley* mentions multiple well-known facts that can easily be found by even a casual search of the internet.

Comment: They kind of do, it's just not very efficient as Russia is a large country, previously accustomized to terrorist attacks and due to fatalistic mindset of Russians.

Comment: This question is unclear, because "more" isn't well-defined. Ukraine is already covertly attacking targets within Russia. If they run 100 such attacks, then you could interpret this question as "why don't they run 101 such attacks"; but if they run 101 such attacks, you could still interpret this question as "why don't they run 102 such attacks", making the question unclear.

Comment: @Allure: I am tangentially interested in the Ukrainian topic (generic EU westerner) so I do not track the numbers. When reading the news I have never seen mention of Ukrainian activity against Russia on their soil, as opposed to hearing about the war on Ukrainian territory. I am not saying that there are none, it is just that they are basically invisible to the casual reader.

Comment: @WoJ that's very surprising. Maybe you're getting an AI-censored version of the news that caters to your specific tastes? E.g. https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-war-attacks-putin-belgorod-b6dcf1f4bc00d3967c54fe038f8dd281, https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/1/3/ukraine-targets-russian-border-regions-in-retaliatory-strikes are from mainstream Western newspapers.

Comment: @Allure: no, it is just that I loosely follow the news and the arguably few mentions of Ukraine attacks are to be weighted against the overall "Russia vs Ukraine" news. I read a generic panel of French news across the political spectrum. Out of curiosity I had a look at Google News (with papers from *l'Humanité" to "Le Figaro", that is from left to right (at least our left to right) and I saw one about an aborted Ukraine attack, then 6 about Russian attacks (or Ukraine defense in their territory). I do not remember seeing the ones you point to but, again, I am just a casual reader

Comment: I am not sure the term *guerilla* applies to the attacks beyond one's own territory (occupied by an enemy). *Covert operations* or something like this is probably more in line with what the Q describes.

Comment: @RogerV. I do not know either - anyway the question has been already butchered^H^H^H^H edited massively, then closed after an equal up- and down-vote so I do not really care. I was not expecting such emotions on a rather bland (but interesting to me) political question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### They are... sort of

These aren't as significant in Western media as they are elsewhere, but Ukraine [has been hitting targets on the Russian side using drones](https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-war-drones-a9fc4ddad80a906e85aacca7354eb317)

> Ukraine sent waves of drones deep into western Russia in more than four hours of nighttime attacks that struck military assets, Russian officials and media reports said Wednesday.

Ukraine officially denies any responsibility for said drone strikes

> Mykhailo Fedorov, Ukraine’s minister of digital transformation, said his country has drones with a range of up to 500 kilometers (300 miles), although he did not take responsibility for any attacks in Russia or Crimea, the peninsula that Russia illegally annexed from Ukraine in 2014.

It's not exactly clear who, where or how said drones are being sent into Russia. That's about as guerilla a tactic as you will see.

Answer (score 5):

First, there have been a few guerrilla attacks within Russian borders by some anti-Putin Russian partisan groups, as well as a number of long-range drone attacks on military and industrial targets. But from the beginning of the war Western allies of Ukraine were concerned about attacks on Russian soil, citing the possibility such might escalate the conflict. I don't think Ukrainian leadership is concerned about the repetitional issues of guerrilla warfare; I think they are concerned that the support of Western allies is contingent on keeping the war within Ukrainian borders.

Comment: Western governments are democracies, and the reputation of the Ukraine is key to maintaining popular support. Without that, governments would have to expend more political capital to justify the subsidies.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other points mentioned, a more obscure form of attack (nearly inspired from the [Taliban tactics](https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/afghan-pilots-assassinated-by-taliban-us-withdraws-2021-07-09/), one might say) was the [targeting of some Russian pilots inside Russia](https://www.pravda.com.ua/eng/news/2024/02/3/7440244/).

Such attacks are difficult to pull off though. Especially if you want to be a stickler to the laws of war, which has somewhat [nebulous and complex rules on perfidy](https://lieber.westpoint.edu/sabotage-law-meaning-misunderstandings/). (According to that fairly amusing piece: infiltrating enemy territory in disguise is not prohibited per se. But carrying out some forms of attack like that is. Oddly enough, placing bombs that go off later is not prohibited though, nor does it require one to break disguise. But shooting someone while in disguise is technically against those rules. Bombs are more likely to kill unintended targets though, of course.)

Another point: while not illegal, saboteurs enjoy less protection under the laws of war. Not that that may be so much of a show stopper, because reportedly Russia [has](https://www.voanews.com/a/russia-says-it-sentenced-more-than-200-ukrainian-pows-/7441156.html) already sentenced hundreds of Ukrainian PoWs for murder, terrorism, and the like. And while Russia [has traded](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82821/what-was-the-selection-criteria-for-people-russia-judges-in-the-azov-trial) some of those back to Ukraine, (sometimes apparently unwittingly, via Turkey), at other times [horrible stuff happened to them](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/aug/06/russian-prison-camp-ukrainians-deaths-donetsk) (and was blamed on Ukraine.)

Comment: Shooting someone while in disguise is against the rules? Stealth technology is a thing in the military.

Comment: @Stančikas: You almost sound [like Trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41870/is-the-f-35-aircraft-literally-invisible?noredirect=1&lq=1). That you can't see it [on radar] from miles away doesn't mean it has no flag painted which you could see from a few meters. Geneva conventions don't prohibit cammo pattern uniforms either. What e.g. AP I prohibits (has clearer language than earlier treaties): is to "“kill, injure or capture an adversary by resort to perfidy,” which includes “the feigning of civilian, non-combatant status.”"

Comment: @Stančikas: according to ICRC commentary, cammo etc. are "ruses of war" and are permitted though https://casebook.icrc.org/a_to_z/glossary/ruse-war Cammo is specifically mentioned in Art 37.2 of AP I https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/en/ihl-treaties/api-1977/article-37

Answer (score 1):

Terrorist attack in case of Ukraine is exclusively a propaganda term. Terrorism is something that is generally not seen as legitimate, while the Article 51 of the UN Charter provides for Ukraine the inherent right of  self-defense. They are allowed to strike anywhere into the territory of Russia as long as they do not specifically *target* civilians (even if they end up killing some).

Guerrilla warfare relies on the support of the local population and intimate knowledge of the terrain. This cannot be done in another country. Sending troops deep behind the enemy lines is costly, they will not survive for long and may not be able to do a lot. There are no legal reasons why Ukraine should not be doing this as long as they take they own weapons.

Guerrilla warfare itself is not prohibited by international law. However guerrilla fighters must adhere to the laws of armed conflict to be afforded protection under those laws. A sniper shooting somebody inside the territory of the enemy should likely identify himself a enemy combatant at the time of firing, but I think he surely has right to hide well while doing so (almost every sniper does).

Comment: I had a hard time finding the proper wording for these attacks that are not officially supported by a government and that happens on the enemy territory. I also used "sabotage" as one of them. The thing I did not want to get into was the emotional impact of the words and keep it as a purely "why don't they do it" kind of question (the "it" being these attacks)

Answer (score 0):

**["Never get involved in a land [guerrilla] war in Asia."](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104366/meaning-of-never-get-involved-in-a-land-war-in-asia-in-the-princess-bride)**

Expanding a bit on @alamar's comment earlier about Russia being a larger country, it's probably worth keeping in mind just how much difference there is between Russia and Ukraine as far as the size of their borders.

[image: A Google Maps view of mostly Europe cut-off around France and Italy, with an view zoomed out to see Russia, zoomed out enough to see Omsk at the far end. Ukraine has been copied and pasted over an area that indicates the distance it covers within it.]

Admittedly, this map is using Mercator Projection, so not all sizes are necessarily aligned, but for them to do guerrilla attacks, they'd have to travel a decent amount of range to get to some cities, especially Moscow. They'd have to travel the entire distance of their country to get to Kazan.

It seems more likely that, rather than trying a guerrilla war in the enemy country if they don't have to, they would likely have such ventures in areas occupied by Russia's invasion into Ukraine.